# Using JavaScript to move node

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table structured as below. As I cannot change anything about how the HTML is created but I can add some lines I want to solve this via JavaScript.

What I want is that:
**(1) the table gets an additional `<thead>` element** 
**(2) the `<tr>` element with class `firstline` becomes a child of `<thead>`**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class= firstline > 
      <th> 1st column  </th>
      <th> 2nd column  </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class= content > 
      <th> foo  </th>
      <th> bat  </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So far, I manage to delete the `<tr class= firstline >` element and I manage to add a `<thead>` element to the table. But I have no clue how to insert the `<tr class= firstline >` into the `<thead>` ???

```
var firstLines = document.getElementsByClassName("firstline");
for (var i=0; i<firstLines.length; i++) {
        var FLparent = firstLines[i].parentNode.parentNode;
        var tbody    = document.createElement("thead")    ;
        FLparent.insertBefore(tbody, FLparent.firstChild); 
        FLparent.firstChild.appendChild(firstLines[i]);
        firstLines[i].parentNode.removeChild(firstLines[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be as simple as:

```
var
  table = document.querySelector('table'),
  tHead = table.insertBefore(document.createElement('thead'), table.firstChild);

tHead.appendChild(
  table.querySelector('tr.firstline')
);
```

http://jsbin.com/ruza/3/

Comment: tweaking it to my particular case: ``var firstLines=document.getElementsByClassName("firstline");
for (var i=0; i<firstLines.length; i++) {
        var table = firstLines[i].parentNode.parentNode;
          tHead = table.insertBefore(document.createElement('thead'), table.firstChild );
          tHead.appendChild( table.querySelector('tr.firstline') );
}`` ... which does it for all the tables.

Comment: One question: Why is it that I do note have to delete the <tr> node?

Comment: @marvin_dpr because if you append a node to another parent, you're moving that particular node. There's no need to delete it beforehand.